# Custom Woocommerce admin side Add item modal

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hello guys i hope you can help me,
the problem is that i need a better product finder at new Order add item in admin side. as i did not find any plugin i thought i could make one modal with filters that can replace the actual one.
The question now is, where can i find the code to modify, whats the best way to do it, is there any plugin that i have not seen? 
I'm very complicated, sorry the image is in spanish

[image]

Thanks c:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is the same as the 'Add Products' of the 'Add new order' page then the filter 'woocommerce_json_search_found_products' will do what you want.

```
# modified from WC_AJAX::json_search_products()
# untested but should point you in the right direction

add_filter( 'woocommerce_json_search_found_products', function( $products ) {
    $term = wc_clean( stripslashes( $_GET['term'] ) );
    # split the term into terms
    $terms = explode( ' ', $term );

    $data_store = WC_Data_Store::load( 'product' );
    $ids = [];
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        # do a search for each term and join the result
        $ids = array_merge( $ids, $data_store->search_products( $term, '', false ) );
    }
    $ids = array_unique( $ids );

    if ( ! empty( $_GET['exclude'] ) ) {
      $ids = array_diff( $ids, (array) $_GET['exclude'] );
    }

    if ( ! empty( $_GET['include'] ) ) {
      $ids = array_intersect( $ids, (array) $_GET['include'] );
    }

    if ( ! empty( $_GET['limit'] ) ) {
      $ids = array_slice( $ids, 0, absint( $_GET['limit'] ) );
    }

    $product_objects = array_filter( array_map( 'wc_get_product', $ids ), 'wc_products_array_filter_editable' );
    $products        = array();

    foreach ( $product_objects as $product_object ) {
      $products[ $product_object->get_id() ] = rawurldecode( $product_object->get_formatted_name() );
    }

    return $products;
 });
```

Comment: Let me know if this hint isn't enough. I use this filter and know it very well.

Comment: i found this `// define the woocommerce_json_search_found_products callback 
function filter_woocommerce_json_search_found_products( $products ) { 
    // make filter magic happen here... 
    return $products; 
}; 
         
// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_json_search_found_products', 'filter_woocommerce_json_search_found_products', 10, 1 );` i would like to filter by tags, any idea ? >.<

Comment: The filter is on an array of product descriptions. However, the index of this array is the product id. So, you can use the product id to get any property of the product. If you want to remove products from the array you can use array_filter(). Let me know if this isn't clear enough.

Comment: i understand that, but the finder actually filter by product name, i mean, when i write for example: Nike air model xyz 22 it only  search that name on products list. i need the list to display all products that have "nike" "shoes" "22" tags, do you know how can i do this? :)

Comment: In this case you need to discard the original array and return a new array that you have constructed. The new array should be indexed by product id and the values should be the product description. I think the description can be anything you want as it is used for display only so no need to match the format exactly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148092/discussion-between-magenta-cuda-and-gabriel-eduardo-toledo).